# WPF C# Textbox IDataErrorInfo Bug - Clicking multiple times, when IsEnabled = true erases text

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, idataerrorinfo

I have created a wpf textbox that is bound to an entity that implements IDataErrorInfo. When the textbox is invalidated (red box around it because it fails the IDataErrorInfo validation) and the textbox's IsEnabled property is set to false, I can click on the textbox multiple times and the text inside of the textbox is erased (string.Empty is passed to the entity).

What is going on here? Is this expected behavior?

Edit: I removed the isEnabled and added isreadonly and focusable. I realized that if I am not clicking in the text box, it erases if the validation fails.

Edit: Then, I removed the focusable and tried again. This time, nothing erased until I click right on the red line representing the validation.

Edit: My textbox lives inside of a DataTemplate inside of a DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate inside of a DataGridTemplateColumn.

The callstack is below:

> MyCode.DLL!MyCode.Models.Entity.PropertyName.set(string value) Line 66  C#
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.SetValue(object item, object value)   Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.UpdateValue(object value)   Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateSource(object value)  Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.UpdateValue()   Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateOverride()    Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Update()    Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.ProcessDirty()  Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Dirty() Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value) Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType, bool isInternal)    Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value)    Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.GetInitialValue(System.Windows.DependencyObject target, out System.Windows.Controls.ValidationError error)  Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(object item)   Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachToContext(System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachAttempt attempt)    Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.MS.Internal.Data.IDataBindEngineClient.AttachToContext(bool lastChance) Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Task.Run(bool lastChance) Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.Run(object arg)   Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.DataBindEngine.OnLayoutUpdated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)    Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.fireLayoutUpdateEvent()    Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout() Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()    Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.BeginEdit(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)  Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedBeginEdit(System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)  Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.OnExecutedBeginEdit(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding.OnExecuted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)  Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.ExecuteCommandBinding(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e, System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding commandBinding)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.FindCommandBinding(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e, System.Windows.Input.ICommand command, bool execute)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.OnExecuted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)  Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.OnExecutedThunk(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)    Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate genericHandler, object target) Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised)    Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool trusted) Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.ExecuteImpl(object parameter, System.Windows.IInputElement target, bool userInitiated)  Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.RoutedCommand.Execute(object parameter, System.Windows.IInputElement target)  Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.BeginEdit(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs editingEventArgs)   Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.OnAnyMouseLeftButtonDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)    Unknown
>       PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell.OnAnyMouseLeftButtonDownThunk(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)    Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate genericHandler, object genericTarget) Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised)    Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, System.Windows.RoutedEvent newEvent)  Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)  Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate genericHandler, object genericTarget) Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised)    Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args)    Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool trusted) Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs input)  Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport inputReport)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.Windows.Input.InputMode mode, int timestamp, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions actions, int x, int y, int wheel)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)   Unknown
>       PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)    Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown
>       WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)  Unknown
>       [AppDomain Transition]

Comment: Can you please post a Code?

Comment: @Hille I will try to post some code later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out why, but I found that using `CellTemplate` and `CellEditingTemplate` fixed my issue.

To the people who downvoted my post and ran off, I'd recommend that you just ignore question in the future if you can't grasp on to the complexity.